# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de autor, atraves de su id de autor en Angular?

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript

En la tabla muestro una lista de libros recorriendo con un `*ngFor` los datos que estan en `bookList$`.
Este `bookList$` no tiene la propiedad de nombre de autor, pero si tiene el id de autor como muestro a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que en la tabla muestre el nombre del autor, para esto en `author.service.ts` tengo la siguiente función:

```js
URL_API = 'http://localhost:4000/authors';

getAuthorById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<Author[]>(`${this.URL_API}/${id}`);
  }
```

en `books.component.ts` implemento el servicio

```
constructor(public authorService: AuthorService){ }
```

En `books.component.html` intenté implementar la función `getAuthorById()` del servicio `authorService`, y pasarle el **id de author**
que tiene `bookList$` de la siguiente manera:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let b of bookList$ | async; index as i">
        <td class="text-center">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ b.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ authorService.getAuthorById(b.id_author) }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">                              
               <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mr-1">Editar</button>
               <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Pero el resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como hago para poder obtener el nombre y mostrarlo en la tabla?

Answer (score 1):

La llamada a `authorService.getAuthorById(b.id_author)` devuelve un Observable, no el nombre de un autor.

Una solución sería usar el pipe `async`, que se suscribe al observable y muestra el resultado una vez que se ha obtenido. Si el resultado es puro texto, debería funcionar, pero en caso de que la respuesta sea un objeto, podrías mostrarlo usando además el pipe `json`, que es equivalente a usar `JSON.stringify`:

```
<td class="text-center">{{ authorService.getAuthorById(b.id_author) | async | json }}</td>
```

De todos modos el método, con ese `this.http.get<Author[]>` sugiere que vas a obtener un array de objetos Author:

```
getAuthorById(id: string): Observable<Author[]> {
  return this.http.get<Author[]>(`${this.URL_API}/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: gracias! usando el async | jason obtengo null como resultado,  hay otra posible solución?

Comment: eso es que llega esa respuesta de backend...